# Define function that takes all derived classes of an Abstract class as argument

Tags: c++, abstract-class

How to solve the following conflict?

1. Define an operator[] in Abstract that returns Abstract. I want to allow function f to use the method. But, this won't work because the corresponding operator[] of DerivedA should return DerivedA. Then, the return type of operator[] of Abstract and the return type of operator[] of DerivedA are not covariant.
2. Not define the method in Abstract. Now function f can't build on the method of Abstract. Possibly this means having to write multiple version of f for each of all derived class of Abstract.

After a while I realize I can enable_if the argument has a certain trait, and simply get rid of the Abstract class. Are there other possible solution?

Code:

```
class Abstract{
    protected:
        int val;
    public:
        //virtual Abstract operator[](int i){} //forget about this.
        virtual ~Abstract(){}
};

class DerivedA : public Abstract{
    public:
        DerivedA(){
            val = 0;
        }
        DerivedA operator[](int i){
            DerivedA temp;
            temp.val = val + i;
        }
};
class DerivedB : public Abstract{
    public:
        DerivedB(){
            val = 0;
        }
        DerivedB operator[](int i){
            DerivedB temp;
            temp.val = val*2 + i;
        }
};

template <typename T>
//some enable_if here to limit type T to
//DerivedA or DerivedB.
T f(T & X){
    return X[1];
}

/*
Abstract f(Abstract & X){
    return X[1];
} //forget about this again. 
*/

int main(void){
    DerivedB B;
    DerivedA A;
    f(B);
    f(A);
}
```

Comment: **–1** This is **not real code**.

Comment: "the code below doesn't work at all" - in no small part due to the plethora of syntax errors, logic errors, and missing identifiers. Give yourself a fighting chance and fix at least those.

Comment: I think if the silly not-real-code example is ignored, this boils down to the problem of covariant function templates, which C++ doesn't support as member functions.

Comment: templates is better than oop. At least for the oop that I know.

Comment: @Cheers and hth: It is real code now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an *error* (thus not SFINAE), you might as well use:

`static_assert(std::is_base_of<Abstract, T>, "Error: not a descendant");`

in your function.

Comment: i don't want an error. Thanks for the answer though. I didn't know is_base_of.

Comment: @rxu: Note that you get the error when it's not a base. Or do you want a different overload in that case?